# Getting size of a nested dictionary and then populate uitableview objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, loops, dictionary

I have this dictionary in objective c:

```
{
awayScore = 2;
awayTeam = "Kode IF";
events =     (
            {
        eventType = "01:00";
        name = "01:00";
    },
            {
        eventType = "01:00";
        name = "01:00";
    }
);
homeScore = 1;
homeTeam = "Partille IF FK ";
time = "01:00";
}
```

Now for populating a tableview i would need to know the size of "events" items so i can return the number of rows. Also how could i iterate then through them? (now I'm thinking when I'm going to use the values to populate the cells)

so 1) How can i get the size of it
and 2) How can i iterate through them and get the different values in uitableview

I know how to iterate through ALL THE KEYS, but since i don't know how to just loop through a specific key that has many items i can't show you what i have done so far

Thanks!!

Comment: "events" is an array.  Take it's `count`.

Comment: Thanks got it working!, wouldd you like to write it as an answer so i can accept it? @HotLicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSon events object should be a JSon Array, so you can fast enumerate through it.

`

```
NSArray *events = jsonDictonary[@"events"];

for (NSDictonary *event in events) {

//parse each event

}
```

Where JsonDictionary is your entire Json object.

Comment: Its an NSDictionary i have not a Json, but i guess the same method applies?

Comment: The way I saw it, I thought it was a JSON, but yes you are correct, the same applies for NSDictionary.